# Have you seen this cat?

Tags: x11, cursor

I am of course referring to the 'screenmate' cat, Neko - looks like this:
[image]

A few years ago, I remember Neko could follow my mouse cursor around, and was a helpful distraction from during long hours of work. I am reminded of this after finding [this extension for XPenguins](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/405/xpenguins/):

[image]

And in my short quest, I have found:

http://users.frii.com/suzannem/neko/index.html#links

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ungattino/?source=directory

The first does work, but within a Window in Wine, as it is a exe:

[image]

The second seems to start and work after running it with `java -jar...`, but seems to crash or disapear sometimes.

**So where can I get Neko from for my computer - so that it can run around the screen like it used to?** <sub>Ubuntu 12.04 & Fedora 19</sub>

---

Here are screenshots from after it was solved:

[image: moggy 1] [image: moggy 2 + penguin]

Comment: Ooh, just noticed this: http://webneko.net/

Comment: Does this mean you still are looking for a solution?

Comment: What do you think @sparticvs? Yes I am :-)

Comment: Got the one from the [2nd Link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ungattino/?source=directory) to work, just disapears for no reason after a while...

Comment: Gentoo offers http://www.daidouji.com/oneko/ but I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: `apt-get install oneko`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - that's annoying, that didn't come up when I searched with `yum` or `apt-cache`...  Please add it in as an answer, along with `sudo yum install oneko`... perhaps also with [this screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SLZMy.png)... :-)

Comment: I still think that `xroach` was even funnier. The source is [here](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/contrib/potluck/src/xroach/)... will try to recompile it when I'll have time.

Comment: `xroach` compiled... but it doesn't work. Time went by...

Comment: @Rmano - don't need to compile it - you can find packages, e.g. [here](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=xroach). Doesn't seem to work though...

Comment: @wilf --- probably it should modified by adding vroot.h (see http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/saucy/xsnow/saucy/revision/1#vroot.h as it was done for `xsnow`. I tried the dirty trick of simply copying and including it but it doesn't work. Well. Back to serious things...

Comment: @Rmano - Seriously? :-) I only came up with this question  when I was half-asleep & couldn't care less...

Comment: xroach moved so fast last I tried it was extremely hard to see.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Oneko](http://www.daidouji.com/oneko/). [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneko), [Fedora](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/oneko). Hasn't been updated since the last millennium so it's got to be the one you remember (also the image matches).

Comment: Yep, that and the melting screen, was one of the thing you used to learn about MIT_MAGIC_COOKIEs for on Sun workstations at uni in the mid 90s. That was a pleasant surprise to find it again a few years back on Debian.

Comment: Just got to get `xsnow` to work now, its right time of year as well... It has been changed since the last millennium, July 2000 apparently...