# What is the name of this interactive animated cat on kde desktop?

Tags: kde, desktop, animation

I've recently found a computer on which there was an animated cat sitting on the system tray. He followed clicks, and looked like this:

[image]

I tried to find what it's called by running `ps -fe > cat.txt`, but after looking through the output and googling items I couldn't identify, I haven't found this program.

Does anyone know what it's called?

Comment: similar, but not sitting around, but chasing the cursor: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105778/have-you-seen-this-cat/105794

Answer (score 1):

After a more thorough search, the program seems to be called AMOR (Amusing Misuse of Resources). It seems to be a KDE-only application. [Here is its github page.](https://github.com/KDE/amor)